# How to delete other apps files? (rooted phone)

Tags: android, file, root

I want to modify my viber database on my app.
i use this code:

```
    File f = new File("/data/data/com.viber.voip/databases/viber_messages");
    boolean b1 = f.setExecutable(true, false);
    boolean b2 = f.setWritable(true, false);
```

but b1,b2 are false.How can it be done?

i use "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify other apps. Your app is sandboxed, that prevents it from modifying other apps. To quote the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean,%20boolean)):

> true if and only if the operation succeeded. If the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname the operation will fail. If the underlying file system does not support execute permission and the value of executable is false, this operation will fail.

The permission "WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" allows you to write to e.g. the SD card or other spaces that are "user- visible".

To modify other apps it's required that your phone is rooted and you must use something like a shell. Take a look a libsuperuser [here](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser). It gives you the option to create a superuser shell (su permissions). You could copy the db into the directory of your app to modify it (remember to set the required permissions).

Comment: so the only way is too be rooted?

Comment: Yes and to use something like a shell (e.g. libsuperuser mentioned from my post).